# Load 3D shapefiles in QGIS 3.0 where Ground Wall Roof Solid are separated

Tags: shapefile, 3d, vector-layer, qgis-3

The brussels region distribute 3D shapefiles in opendata.

[http://urbisdownload.gis.irisnet.be/fr/download/](https://s.irisnet.be/v1/AUTH_ce3f7c74-fbd7-4b46-8d85-53d10d86904f/UrbAdm3D/UrbAdm3D_SHP.zip)

The spatial objects are separated in many files :

- Ground
- Wall
- Roof
- Solid

[image]

There is no 3D informations about 3D in attributes.
[image]

AND the geometries are flat:

[image]

How to render 3d?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. *Right-click* each layer and go to:

   ```
   Properties > 3D View > Enable 3d renderer
   ```

   You can leave the default settings and click *Apply*. Do this with the other layers (or copy/paste the style as this will also transfer the 3D renderer settings).

   [image: 3D settings]

---

2. Then from the menubar, go to:

   ```
   View > New 3D Map View
   ```

   When you toggle your layers, you should see them in 3D.

   **Note that I used `No symbols` for the symbology of each layer as these would be shown in 2D underneath**

---

---

Example:

- Walls + ground:

  [image: Example 1]

---

- Walls + ground + roof:

  [image: Example 2]